# Hiding code comments in listings

Tags: listings

I'm using listings package and `\lstinputstring` command to insert code from a file.  Is it possible to hide code comments in inserted code? I'm using a language in which # starts a comment and it lasts until the end of line.  I tried to do this with escapeinside option, but I think I don't understand how it works.

Comment: From your comment below you say that you want lines with only comments to be ignored. In this case I'd recommend just pre-processing the file.

Comment: related: [How to strip a listing of all (line and block) comments without leaving white space?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159834/how-to-strip-a-listing-of-all-line-and-block-comments-without-leaving-white-sp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd just cheat, and specify `commentstyle=\color{white}`.  This is even used in the manual :-)  It does have the defect that if you print on non-white paper you'll see it, but that's usually not happening.  Of course, if you have a non-white background, just use the background color instead.

---

**Edit:** For block comments, you can also use `morecomment=[is]{/*}{*/}`, where the `i` makes the comment completely invisible; however, this doesn't work for single-line comments, instead deleting all of the source code after the first single-line comment it finds.

Comment: If I have lines with only comments it leaves blank lines=(  I tried negative \vspace in commentstyle but I guess it doesn't work in verbatim environment.

Comment: Hmm, that'll be harder.  What Will said might be best—preprocess your file first.  That said, I'll think on it and see if I can come up with any hacks.

Comment: Having poked around in the manual: if you specify `morecomment=[is]{/*}{*/}`, the `i` makes the comment completely invisible, but I can't get this to work right with line comments (it just deletes the whole rest of the text after the first comment, not even reserving space for it).

Comment: I got away with `morecomment=[is]{\#\%}{\#:}`, this required only minor changes to source files and looks well.  Thanks for the `i` tip.

Comment: @maarons: Glad that worked out for you—I added it to the answer, for completeness's sake.