# How to strip a listing of all (line and block) comments without leaving white space?

Tags: listings

I'm looking for an easy and robust way to strip all the comments from a listing. My approach (passing `\@gobble` to the `commentstyle` key) correctly removes all the one-line comments and block comments. However, the white space left behind by by block comments remains, creating useless gaps in my listing. See the screenshot below (the red rectangle is my emphasis). Any idea?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lstset%
{%
  basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
  morecomment  = [l]{//},
  morecomment  = [s]{/*}{*/},
  frame        = single,
  commentstyle = \itshape\color[gray]{.5},
  rulecolor    = \color{black},
  breaklines,
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.c}
#include <stdio.h> 
/*
 block comment taking up white space
*/
main()
{
    float fahr, celsius;
    float lower, upper, step;
    lower   = 0;    /* lower limit of temperature scale */
    upper   = 300;  /* upper limit */
    step    = 20;   /* step size */
    celsius = lower;
    printf("\nCelsius\tFahr\n");
    while (celsius <= upper)   
    {
        fahr = (9.0/5.0) * celsius+32.0;
        printf("%3.0f\t%6.1f\n", celsius, fahr);
        celsius = celsius + step;
    }
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\lstinputlisting[caption={with comments}]{sample.c}
\lstinputlisting[caption={without comments},commentstyle={\@gobble}]{sample.c}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would just go for a code beautifier avoid using tex/latex for this one.

Comment: @user2485710 Thanks, but this question is specifically about LaTeX and the `listings` package. But if you know of a code beautifier that allows for typesetting code in LaTeX and switch the comments off with a flip of a switch, I'm interested...

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5625/hiding-code-comments-in-listings

Comment: @aganders3 No. My feeling is the same as expressed in [the first comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5625/hiding-code-comments-in-listings#comment8724_5626) on the answer: I don't want any blank space left behind block comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**First version**

Below I defined two list styles, where the first is loaded by the second, and then the first comment definitions are overwritten. For block comments the **i**nvisible variant is used. This does not work for line comments, though (more on this at bottom of this answer). But you can add the command you already used as second optional argument, what works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{commentcolor}{gray}{.5}
\definecolor{rulecolor}{named}{black}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{c_with_comments}%
{
  basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
  language=c,
  morecomment  = [l]{//},
  morecomment  = [s]{/*}{*/},
  frame        = single,
  commentstyle = \itshape\color{commentcolor},
  rulecolor    = \color{rulecolor},
  breaklines,
}
\makeatletter
\lstdefinestyle{c_without_comments}%
{
  style=c_with_comments,
  morecomment  = [l][\@gobble]{//},
  morecomment  = [is]{/*}{*/},
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.c}
#include <stdio.h> 
/*
 block comment taking up white space
*/
main()
{
    float fahr, celsius;
    float lower, upper, step;
    lower   = 0;    /* lower limit of temperature scale */
    upper   = 300;  // upper limit
    step    = 20;   // step size
    celsius = lower;
    printf("\nCelsius\tFahr\n");
    while (celsius <= upper)   
    {
        fahr = (9.0/5.0) * celsius+32.0;
        printf("%3.0f\t%6.1f\n", celsius, fahr);
        celsius = celsius + step;
    }
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[caption={with comments},style=c_with_comments]{sample.c}
\lstinputlisting[caption={without comments},style=c_without_comments]{sample.c}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of example output]

**Second version**

The second version differs in only one line. The output is the same, but this version is quite probably safer (thanks @tohecz for the hint, cf. his comment below this answer). Replace `\@gobble` with `\nullfont`:

```
  morecomment  = [l][\nullfont]{//},
```

`\@gobble` is defined in a way, that it needs one argument, and there may be situations, that not the whole line after `//` is considered as such.

---

Unfortunately the quite simple approach (using the invisible variant) does only work with block comments. For *line comments* the output is **cut until the end of the whole listing**! Confer wrong code and output in [edit revision 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/160334/3) of this answer.

I darkly remembered and had to search for again, but here a cite from  `listings` documentation:

> Eventually, you might want to use the prefix i on any comment type. Then the
>   comment is not only invisible, it is completely discarded from the output!

No warning for one line comments. Looks like a bug in `listings`, at least this must be documented.

Comment: For line comments, depending on whether you want to just hide them or avoid people accessing them, you can print them white.

Comment: @tohecz: But only when the background is white, too. It becomes an impossible task, when the background is shaded.

Comment: Well ... I dunno ... locallz changing to a null font? I think it's described somewhere in the TeXbook how to achieve that, but I really really don't know

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's a start. I see two problems: 1) the block comments still leaves a blank line behind (because of the newline right after the closing delimiter), but there may be a way to gobble that; and 2) you have to redefine the `morecomment` with the `i` modifier, which kind of lacks automation. I'm not going to award you with the bounty just yet, because I want to see if a more satisfactory solution can be devised...

Comment: Actually, your answer is not bad at all. The fact that one line is left behind block comments is actually quite desirable, and you can automate the removal of comments by defining a new key: `\lst@Key{turncommentsoff}{false}[t]{\lst@CommentKey\@empty{[l][\nullfont]{//}}\lst@CommentKey\relax{[is]{/*}{*/}}}`. Feel free to add that to your answer, if you want.