# minted: Hiding comments in code?

Tags: minted

Is there anyway to have minted hide code comments completely? This is related to [How to strip a listing of all (line and block) comments without leaving white space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159834/how-to-strip-a-listing-of-all-line-and-block-comments-without-leaving-white-sp)

But that question is about the listings package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code creates a new environment, `mintednc`, that strips comments completely. You can add it to the preamble. I've tested it with both C and Python. It's possible that it will need a few tweaks to deal with additional languages.

This code works by creating a custom version of `\minted@pygmentize`. In this customized version, the highlighted Pygments output is opened via a `\write18` Python command, and any line beginning with `\PY{c}`, `\PY{c+cm}`, or `\PY{c+c1}` is discarded.  These are the Pygments highlighting commands with arguments that indicate comments.  This approach completely eliminates any line that begins with a comment.  But inline comments that follow code would be left intact.

**Edit in response to question in comments**: Adding support for `\inputminted` is just a matter of creating a wrapper command (`\inputmintednc`) that uses the customized `\minted@pygmentize`. I've added this at the end of the code.

**Edit in response to error messages in comments**: It looks like you are using the development version of `minted`. The patch only works for `minted` 1.7. I've added code that works (for now, anyway) with the development version.

#### Code for `minted 1.7` (which is in current TeX distros)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\minted@pygmentize@stripcomments}[2][\jobname.pyg]{
  \def\minted@cmd{pygmentize -l #2 -f latex -F tokenmerge
    \minted@opt{gobble} \minted@opt{texcl} \minted@opt{mathescape}
    \minted@opt{startinline} \minted@opt{funcnamehighlighting}
    \minted@opt{linenos} -P "verboptions=\minted@opt{extra}"
    -o \jobname.out.pyg #1}
  \immediate\write18{\minted@cmd}
  % For debugging, uncomment:
  %\immediate\typeout{\minted@cmd}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}
   {}
   {\begin{minted@colorbg}{\minted@opt@bgcolor}}
  % add command to strip comments
  \immediate\write18{\detokenize{python -c "f = open(\"}\jobname\detokenize{.out.pyg\");
    txt = f.readlines(); f.close();
    txt = [line for line in txt if not line.lstrip().startswith(\"\\PY{c}\") and not line.lstrip().startswith(\"\\PY{c+c1}\") and not line.lstrip().startswith(\"\\PY{c+cm}\")];
    f = open(\"}\jobname\detokenize{.out.pyg\", \"w\");
    f.write(\"\".join(txt)); f.close();"}}
  % end
  \input{\jobname.out.pyg}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}
   {}
   {\end{minted@colorbg}}
  \DeleteFile{\jobname.out.pyg}}

\newenvironment{mintednc}[2][]{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \let\minted@pygmentize\minted@pygmentize@stripcomments
  \begin{minted}[#1]{#2}}{\end{minted}}
\newcommand{\inputmintednc}[3][]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\minted@pygmentize\minted@pygmentize@stripcomments
  \inputminted[#1]{#2}{#3}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

#### Code for current [development version](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) of `minted`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\minted@inputpyg@stripcomments}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@optcmd@bgcolor}{}}%
    {}%
    {\begin{minted@colorbg}{\minted@optcmd@bgcolor}}%
  % add command to strip comments
  \immediate\write18{\detokenize{python -c "from io import open;
    import re;
    pattern = re.compile(r\"\\PYG([a-z]+)\");
    f = open(\"}\minted@outputdir\minted@infile\detokenize{\", encoding=\"}\minted@encoding\detokenize{\");
    txt = f.read(); f.close();
    p = pattern.search(txt).groups()[0];
    p1 = \"\\PYG\"+p+\"{c}\";
    p2 = \"\\PYG\"+p+\"{c+c1}\";
    p3 = \"\\PYG\"+p+\"{c+cm}\";
    txt = [line for line in txt.splitlines(True) if not line.lstrip().startswith(p1) and not line.lstrip().startswith(p2) and not line.lstrip().startswith(p3)];
    f = open(\"}\jobname\detokenize{.out.pyg\", \"w\", encoding=\"}\minted@encoding\detokenize{\");
    f.write(\"\".join(txt)); f.close();"}}
  % end
  \input{\jobname.out.pyg}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@optcmd@bgcolor}{}}%
    {}%
    {\end{minted@colorbg}}%
}
\newenvironment{mintednc}[2][]{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \let\minted@inputpyg\minted@inputpyg@stripcomments
  \begin{minted}[#1]{#2}}{\end{minted}}
\newcommand{\inputmintednc}[3][]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\minted@inputpyg\minted@inputpyg@stripcomments
  \inputminted[#1]{#2}{#3}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Would it be easy to make this work with `\inputminted` as well as the environment?

Comment: @Sahand I've modified the answer. It's pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying it now. What version of latex and pygmentize did you use to test this? I am getting errors such as `! Undefined control sequence.  \minted@cmd ...-f latex -F tokenmerge \minted@opt`

Comment: @Sahand I'm using TeX Live 2014 and Pygments 2.0pre. The error message you are getting can be caused by using the development version of `minted`; I wrote the original code for `minted` 1.7. I've added code that works with the development version (at least for now).

Comment: Nice. This works perfectly with TeX Live 2014, Minted v2.0-alpha3 and Pygments 2.0rc1. Thank you!