# Delete comment on input with listing

Tags: listings, code

How i can deledete comment from listings code?
I included source code file with `\lstinputlisting{file.m}` where file.m is matlab file. I want delete comment from file.
`% This is a comment
function var = myfunction()`

I tried to use comment `commentstyle=\color{white}` but the result isn't as I expected cause between code there are some withe line that i want totally remove.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159834/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5625/35864 can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the right delimiters instead of the ones in my code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{morecomment=[is]{/*}{*/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
begin /* comment */ end
/* no comment but a blank line remains */
begin/* comment */end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: example_image]

Unfortunately, you cannot get rid of the blank line.

**Reference**: [Delimiters in listings manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf#subsection.3.3)

Comment: I didn't saw the comment from moewe. I think that the links that he provided are more useful than my anwer. ;)