# How do I automatically exclude the comments from the listings?

Tags: listings, comments

While using the `listings` package, I would like to automatically exclude the comments from the input code file.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5626/14103) suggests *whitening* the comments. But that is not exactly what I am looking for. I want the comment lines to be completely excluded.

I don't think that an MWE is needed. Still, I am including one just to make it faster for the potential responders to readily start trying.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.c}
  /* This is a multiline 
  comment. */
  #include <stdio.h>
  void main()
  {
    // Also a single-line comment.
    printf("Hello\n");
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

% I would like to automatically not include the comments
\lstinputlisting[language=C]{\jobname.c}

\end{document}
```

I understand that the comments and actual codes in the same line will further complicate the issue. However, a solution for independent single and multiline comments will suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.c}
  /* This is a multiline 
  comment. */
  #include <stdio.h>
  void main()
  {
    // Also a single-line comment.
    printf("Hello\n");
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language = C}

\lstset{
morecomment=[is]{//}{\^^M} ,
morecomment=[is]{/*}{*/}
}

\lstinputlisting{\jobname.c}

\end{document}
```

In the instructions `morecomment=[is]{//}{\^^M}` and `morecomment=[is]{/*}{*/}`, the letter `i` in option means *invisible*. The letter `s` means that there will be two delimiters specified after.

`\^^M` is a TeX syntax for the character of end of line

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Immense thanks. It would be nice to add a few lines on how the solution works.

Comment: You are right. I have added some explanations.